# Error inserting Full XML in SQL Server 2008 using Entity Framework

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, sql-server-2008-r2

Hi I am trying to insert a XML file in to SQL Server table filed of type XML

but this is giving me error as below

This is my C# logic

```
  using (Entities context = new Entities())
            {
                context.usp_BF_StoreEligibilityResponse(ID, XML);
}
```

this is my Stored Procedure

```
 UPDATE  MyTable
SET     ResponseXML = cast('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Interchange segment-terminator="~" element-separator="*" sub-element-separator="&gt;">
  <ISA>
    <!--Author Information Qualifier-->
    <ISA01>00<!--No Authorization Information Present--></ISA01>
    <!--Author Information-->
    <ISA02>          </ISA02>
    <!--Security Information Qualifer-->
    <ISA03>01<!--Password--></ISA03>
    <!--Security Information-->
    <ISA04>JILITTQQPK</ISA04>
    <!--Interchange ID Qualifier-->
    <ISA05>ZZ<!--Mutually Defined--></ISA05>
    <!--Interchange Sender ID-->
    <ISA06>S00000000000001</ISA06>
    <!--Interchange ID Qualifier-->
    <ISA07>ZZ<!--Mutually Defined--></ISA07>
    <!--Interchange Receiver ID-->
    <ISA08>T00000000021261</ISA08>
    <!--Interchange Date-->
    <ISA09>120328</ISA09>
    <!--Interchange Time-->
    <ISA10>1539</ISA10>
    <!--Inter Control Standards Identifier-->
    <ISA11>&#x1F;</ISA11>
    <!--Inter Control Version Number-->
    <ISA12>00501</ISA12>
    <!--Inter Control Number-->
    <ISA13>021443719</ISA13>
    <!--Acknowlegment Requested-->
    <ISA14>0<!--No Acknowledgment Requested--></ISA14>
    <!--Usage Indicator-->
    <ISA15>T<!--Test Data--></ISA15>
    <!--Component Element Separator-->
    <ISA16>
      <ISA1601 />
      <ISA1602 />
    </ISA16>
  </ISA>
  <TA1>
    <!--Interchange control number-->
    <TA101>0fa080e2-</TA101>
    <!--Interchange Date-->
    <TA102>120328</TA102>
    <!--Interchange Time-->
    <TA103>1639</TA103>
    <!--Interchange ACK Code-->
    <TA104>R<!--Interchange rejected/suspended--></TA104>
    <!--Interchange Note Code-->
    <TA105>018</TA105>
  </TA1>
  <IEA>
    <!--Number of Included Functional Groups-->
    <IEA01>0</IEA01>
    <!--Interchange Control Number-->
    <IEA02>021443719</IEA02>
  </IEA>
</Interchange>' AS XML)
WHERE   EligibilityID = 13
```

Error Message

```
Msg 9420, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
XML parsing: line 25, character 17, illegal xml character
    enter code here
```

This is the line causing this error
**`<ISA11>&#x1F;</ISA11>`**

this when i preview in Visual Studio XML view or HTML view
it looks like this **`<ISA11></ISA11>`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says it's all. Given XML is invalid XML since `&#x1F;` is invalid text sequence. If you want such text it must be entered as `&amp;#x1F;` (`&amp;` is an XML escape sequence for `&` symbol). Alternatively, you can escape string by enclosing it with a CDATA (character data) section: `<![CDATA[&#x1F;]]>`.

Comment: correct. my problem is this XML is dynamically generated in response(Routed from third party service)to my XMLRequest. How can i validate it and fix such problems before i try to insert this in my Table

Comment: Well for now i can live with this solution. I did string replace for & with &amp; - Thank you

Comment: @HaBo well, way to fix depends on your situation. If you can't control XML process generation, then you have no other choice, but fix it manually in text form.

Comment: It is a nice workaround for serializing it but how do you go about deserializing? I am having same issue when serializing &#x2;